# Apply array operator distributively in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types, conditional-types

Let's say I have a type which is a union of literals:

```
type X = "a" | "b" | "c";
```

Now I want to introduce a new type signifying a union of arrays of *each* type in X. In other words, I want to apply the array operator distributively over the union.

Just adding the array operator on the type doesn't do what I want – this will permit a mixed array e.g.

```
type Y = X[]; // ("a" | "b" | "c")[]
const xs: Y = ["a", "b"]; // valid
```

However, conditional types have the distributive property that I seek. I seem to be able to achieve my goal by using them in conjunction with a condition that never gets fulfilled:

```
type Arrayify<T> = T extends never ? never : T[];
type Y = Arrayify<X>; // "a"[] | "b"[] | "c"[]
const xs: Y = ["a", "b"]; // invalid
```

As far as I can tell it solves my problem, but it feels a little backwards to take the detour through conditional types only to get the distributivity. Is there a better, more conventional way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is the right one. Using conditional types for distribution is the way to accomplish this. The recommended patterns to get just the distributive behavior is `T extends T` or `T extends unknown`, but yours works just fine as well in this case.

```
type Arrayify<T> = T extends T ? T[] : never;
```

Comment: I just realised there's a small complication applying this approach to booleans, since they are defined as `true | false` unions.  Thus, `Arrayify<boolean>` will result in `true[] | false[]` and not `boolean[]`.  Is there any way of "blocking" the distributivity?

Comment: @HannesPetri the usual way to block distributivity  is to use a tuple. This should work : `type Arrayify<T> = [T] extends [boolean] ? T[] : T extends T ? T[] : never;
` although you will still get strange distribution over enums.